# show() method does not open window

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using a mac and when I do the following with matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import pylab as P

...
plt.plot(x,y)  
plt.show() <-- nothing happens
plt.savefig('figure.png') <-- works fine
```

So, `plt.show` does not open a window or anything while `plt.savefig` works fine.

What could be the problem?

Comment: title says `show()` dont work. questions says `.plot` don't work. Which is it? `plt.show()` is the normal way to open the figure.

Comment: Ah, sorry I made a mistake in my code citation. Just corrected it

Comment: You are still saying "So, plt.plot does not open a window". But you mean "show()", right?

Comment: Yes right, I mean plt.show()

Comment: In my machine, the plt.show() trigger to open up a 'default program to use' pop up. I accidentally choose VS Code. How to reset it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pyplot will only pop up a figure window if

```
matplotlib.rcParams['interactive'] == True
```

This is the case if you:

- have previous called `plt.ion()` in your script, or
- equivalently, called `matplotlib.interactive(True)`, or
- started an ipython session with the `--pylab` option at the command line.

When interactive mode is off, you generally have to call `plt.show()` explicitly to make the figure window pop up.  This is because we often want to call plot multiple times to draw various things *before* displaying the figure (which is a blocking call).

---

*Edit (after the question was modified)*:

One reason for `plt.show()` not popping up a figure window is that you haven't activated an interactive backend.  Check the output of `plt.get_backend()` - if it returns `'agg'`, for example, you have a non-interactive backend.

If this is your problem, you may add lines like

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('MacOSX')
```

At the start of your script to specify the backend.  This needs to be placed before any other matplotlib related imports.

To make such a change permanent, you can specify a different backend as default by modifying your matplotlib rcfile.  The location of this file is found by calling `matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()`.

Comment: tooms issue seems to be that `show()` does not open a window. Looks like he does not expect `plot()` to open one.

Answer (score 2):

For me I had some code like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
figure = plt.Figure()
axes = figure.add_subplot()
axes.plot([1,2], [1,2])
plt.show()
```

plt.show() didn't block or do anything. If I changed the code to this, then it worked:

```
figure = plt.Figure()
plt.plot([1,2], [1,2])
plt.show()
```

My issue was that I had multiple plots to show in one subplot, so I needed the axes. This was the fix:

```
figure, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.plot([1,2], [1,2])
plt.show()
```