# Matplotlib: ion(): Why draw() for GTK3Agg but pause(s) for Qt4Agg?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to update a figure in matplotlib after each time step of a simulation.

I have managed to do this with:

```
import time, math

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use(u'Qt4Agg') # use some backend
    # (c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21836184 for .use())
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure()
sub = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

x = [i/100. for i in range(-500, 500)]
sin = lambda x : [math.sin(i) for i in x]

axis, = sub.plot(x, sin(x), 'r')

shift = 0.1
while shift < 5:
    shift += 0.01
    x = [i+shift for i in x]
    axis.set_ydata(sin(x))
    plt.pause(0.0001) # was plt.draw()
```

During the course of coming up with this solution I was almost getting mad because the `Qt4Agg` backend did now work properly with the `draw()` command where now there is a `plt.pause(0.0001)` command.

Now it works, but I get the following warning:

```
``/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py:2399: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Using default event loop until function specific to this GUI is implemented
  warnings.warn(str, mplDeprecation)``
```

I also tried the `GTK3Agg` backend, but I am not sure if the computers where we want to run the project support it. Most surprisingly this backend worked with `plt.draw()` (except for the fact that the window freezes) but throws the following warnings and errors when running it with `plt.pause(0.0001)`:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py:2399: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Using default event loop until function specific to this GUI is implemented
  warnings.warn(str, mplDeprecation)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subplot_demo.py", line 24, in <module>
    plt.pause(0.0001) # was plt.draw()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 199, in pause
    canvas.start_event_loop(interval)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py", line 370, in start_event_loop
    FigureCanvasBase.start_event_loop_default(self,timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2407, in start_event_loop_default
    self.flush_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py", line 365, in flush_events
    Gtk.main_iteration(True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: main_iteration() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
```

I assume now that `pause()` is deprecated (as it proved also difficult to find some useful documentation about it) but still stick to it with the `Qt4Agg` backend as I am sure that PyQt4 will be installed on the target systems.

I now wonder: How do I correctly `draw()` with the `Qt4Agg`? The `draw()` call is not working, `pause()` deprecated - what can I do? (On a side note: What exactly went wrong in the `pause()`-call of the `GTK3Agg` backend?)

Some notes on versions:

```
Ubuntu: 12.04, Matplotlib: 1.4.3, Python: 2.7.3, GCC 4.6.3, PyQt: 4.8.1
```